# How to generate open token?

Tags: pingfederate

How to generate open token with the help of `agent_config` file that will get from ping federate?

I have received `agent_config` file from ping federate and I am trying to generate open token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agent agent = new Agent("agent-config.txt");

Map userInfo = new HashMap();

userInfo.put(Agent.TOKEN_SUBJECT, "username");

String openToken=agent.writeToken(userInfo);

Answer (score 1):

The only supported method for OpenToken generation is by using a [PingFederate Integration Kit](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/resources/downloads/pingfederate.html) from Ping Identity. If you are not a customer holding a PingFederate license, you are not licensed to use these kits, and must integrate via a standard of some sort, like SAML or OAuth.